valgrind shows memory leak in my program in c (two versions)
int main()
{             
   double (*arr)[COLS] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * ROWS);
   assert(arr!= NULL);
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      {
         arr[i][j] = 0.0;   
      }
   }
   
   //diagonal
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i] = 4;
   }

   //SUB diagonal
   for (int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i - 1] = -1;
   }

   //top diagonal
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i + 1] = -1;
   }

   //printing  the whole array
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      {
         printf("%lf ", arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   printf("###################\n");
   //RHS
   double* b = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(b != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      b[j] = 1;
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", b[j]);
   } 

   printf("--------------------\n");

   //x_old
   double* x_old = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(x_old != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      x_old[j] = 0.0;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", x_old[j]);
   }
   printf("******************\n");

   //x_new
   double* x_new = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(x_new != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      x_new[j] = 0.0;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", x_new[j]);
   }
   printf("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
    
   free((double*)arr);
   free(b);
   free(x_old);
   free(x_new);
   return 0;
}

AND THE SECOND VERSION
int main()
{ 
   //allocation
   
   double** arr = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(*arr));//pointer to an array with rows
   if(arr != NULL){
      for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
         //allocate memory for each row
         arr[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(*arr[i]));
         assert(arr[i] != NULL);
      }
   }
   
  
   //diagonal
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i] = 4;
   }

   //subdiagonal
   for (int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i - 1] = -1;
   }

   //top diagonal
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      arr[i][i + 1] = -1;
   }

   //printing  the whole array
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      {
         printf("%lf ", arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   printf("###################\n");

   //RHS
   double* b= malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(b != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      b[j] = 1;
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", b[j]);
   }

   printf("--------------------\n");

   //x_old
   double* x_old = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(x_old != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      x_old[j] = 0.0;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", x_old[j]);
   }
   printf("******************\n");

   //x_new
   double* x_new = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWS);
   assert(x_new != NULL);
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      x_new[j] = 0.0;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      printf("%lf\n", x_new[j]);
   }
   printf("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
      
   free(x_new);
   free(x_old);
   free(b); 
   //in this loop the mistake
   for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
      if(array[i] != NULL){
         free(array[i]);
         arr[i] = NULL;
      }
   }
   free(arr); 
   return 0;
}

the output of valgrind in both cases
==9955== 
==9955== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9955==     in use at exit: 1,050 bytes in 33 blocks
==9955==   total heap usage: 35 allocs, 2 frees, 2,074 bytes allocated
==9955== 
==9955== 27 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==9955==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9955==    by 0x491458E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==9955==    by 0x10F43C: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x11EB69: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x10CB65: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x4895D8F: (below main) (libc_start_call_main.h:58)
==9955== 
==9955== 31 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==9955==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9955==    by 0x11E154: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x11EB69: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x10CB65: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x4895D8F: (below main) (libc_start_call_main.h:58)
==9955== 
==9955== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==9955==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9955==    by 0x11E004: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x11EB44: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x10CB65: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x4895D8F: (below main) (libc_start_call_main.h:58)
==9955== 
==9955== 960 bytes in 30 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==9955==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9955==    by 0x11E004: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x11EADF: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x10CB65: ??? (in /usr/bin/dash)
==9955==    by 0x4895D8F: (below main) (libc_start_call_main.h:58)
==9955== 
==9955== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9955==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9955==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9955==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9955==    still reachable: 1,050 bytes in 33 blocks
==9955==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9955== 
==9955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your post to make it much more readable!

I recommend not using C unless you are forced to have lowest common denominator interfaces. You will be able to do things like this with C++ libraries like Eigen and Armadillo without all the nonsense of manually allocating memory and they will be as fast if not faster than your bug prone re-inventing the wheel.
Don't cast the return from malloc in C.
Consider using memset to initialize your values in C (or use C++ which can automate initialization with constructors).
The Valgrind logs you posted are for your shell, not for your test exe. You need to do one of two things.
Either modify your wrapper script so that it runs your test exe in Valgrind.
Or run Valgrind such that it also traces child processes. For instance
valgrind --trace-children=yes --log-file=memcheck.%p.log wrapper.dsh

This will produce one log file per process. You need to find which one is for your test exe and look at that.

You can report the leaks in dash to Debian but I doubt that they will ever git fixed.

+1 for not reinventing the wheel.  Rolling your own matrix library is foolhardy when there are existing well-tested open source libraries.
